# Intuition - dot product doesn't change under rotation

Tags: inner-products

For definiteness let $a:(x_1,y_1),b:(x_2,y_2)$ be *unit* position vectors:
$$a \cdot b = x_1x_2+y_1y_1 = \cos (\phi)$$

where $\phi$ is the angle between $a,b$.
Clearly the angle $\phi$ doesn't change when we rotate the plane.
However I'm finding it hard to see how the sum of products $x_1x_2+y_1y_2$ remains constant.

I feel an explanation using coordinate geometry helps; that is by manipulating $x,y$ coordinates of position vectors $a,b$,  how to see the following product remains constant?  $$\cos a\cos b +\sin a \sin b$$

Comment: One way to think about it is that inner products encode angle and length information about vectors. Since rotations preserve the angles between vectors and lengths they preserve inner products as well.

Comment: $e^{ip}a\cdot e^{ip}b=(\cos p x_1-\sin p y_1,\sin p x_1+\cos p y_1)\cdot (\cos p x_2-\sin p y_2,\sin p x_2+\cos p y_2)$  computes to $a\cdot b$ easily, where do you get lost?

Comment: @ManuelOcaña complex algebra is awesome! so i want to better understand how the product $e^{ip}a\cdot e^{ip}b$ is same as $a\cdot b$ for all $p$

Comment: $$e^{ip}a\cdot e^{ip}b=(\cos p x_1-\sin p y_1,\sin p x_1+\cos p y_1)\cdot (\cos p x_2-\sin p y_2,\sin p x_2+\cos p y_2) \\= x_1x_2(\cos^2p+\sin^2p) + y_1y_2(\cos^2p+\sin^2p) \\= x_1x_2+y_1y_2$$

slick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(x_1,y_1)\mapsto(\cos(\vartheta)x_1-\sin(\vartheta)y_1,\sin(\vartheta)x_1+\cos(\vartheta)y_1)$ under an anticlockwise $2$-d rotation matrix by angle $\vartheta$, and likewise for $(x_2,y_2)$, then, calling the new points $a',b'$:

$$\begin{align}a'\cdot b'&=[(\cos(\vartheta)x_1-\sin(\vartheta)y_1)\cdot(\cos(\vartheta)x_2-\sin(\vartheta)y_2)]\\&+[(\cos(\vartheta)y_1+\sin(\vartheta)x_1)\cdot(\cos(\vartheta)y_2+\sin(\vartheta)x_2)]\\&=[\cos^2(\vartheta)x_1x_2+\sin^2(\vartheta)y_1y_2-\sin(\vartheta)\cos(\vartheta)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)]\\&+[\cos^2(\vartheta)y_1y_2+\sin^2(\vartheta)x_1x_2+\sin(\vartheta)\cos(\vartheta)(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)]\\&=(\cos^2(\vartheta)+\sin^2(\vartheta))x_1x_2+(\cos^2(\vartheta)+\sin^2(\vartheta))y_1y_2\\&=x_1x_2+y_1y_2\\&=a\cdot b\end{align}$$

If the very first step is confusing, study carefully the rotation described below:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\vartheta)&-\sin(\vartheta)\\\sin(\vartheta)&\cos(\vartheta)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Or using matrices, if $R$ is an orthogonal matrix ($R^tR=I$), we write vectors as columns, and $a'=Ra$, $b'=Rb$, then $$a'\cdot b' = (a')^tb = (Ra)^t(Rb)=a^tR^tRb=a^tb = a\cdot b.$$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang FShrike so essentially this works because the rotation matrix is orthonormal:  $$Ra\cdot Rb = a\cdot b$$ by your transposes manipulation above. You're awesome XD

Answer (score 3):

Since $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors, we can find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $a = (\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$ and $b = (\cos\beta, \sin\beta)$. Then
$$
a \cdot b=  \cos\alpha\,\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\,\sin\beta = \cos(\beta-\alpha)
$$
So, the dot product depends only on the angle $\beta-\alpha$ between the two vectors.